# vlookup and replace - performance improvement

Tags: vba, excel, replace, vlookup

I want to create a macro which will vlookup in another sheet and change the value in the vlook up cell by another user defined value.

I wrote a very basic code which full fills my need, but it is very slow and its one run takes almost 3 minutes.

Can you please suggest an easier way out or just suggest what is wrong with my code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim myLookup
    Dim i As Integer
    i = Sheets("Modify Order").Cells(5, 2).Value
     For Each myCell In Sheets("Customer List").Range("E:E")
         If myCell.Value = Sheets("Modify Order").Cells(4, 2).Value Then
         myCell.Offset(0, i).Value = Sheets("Modify Order").Cells(7, 2).Value
         End If
        Next myCell

MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

Comment: How many rows do you have in Column E? You may try to find the last row that contains data before you start the for loop in order to not spend any time checking cells that don't contain any data.

Comment: Try adding these two lines and tell me if it improves.

`LastRow = Sheets("Customer List").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row`
`For Each myCell In Sheets("Customer List").Range("E1:E" & LastRow & "")`

Comment: May be better on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba?sort=newest&pageSize=50)

Comment: How many used rows in your sheet?  What percentage of those do you expect to get a match to 'Modify Order!'B4?

Answer (score 1):

It is always very slow iterating cell-by-cell: better to use  variant arrays instead:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim vArrColE As Variant
Dim vArrColChange As Variant
Dim myLookup As Variant
Dim myChangeTo As Variant
Dim j As Long
Dim jLastRow As Long
Dim kCol As Long
Dim nChanged As Long
Dim lCalc As Long

lCalc = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

myLookup = Sheets("Modify Order").Cells(4, 2).Value2
myChangeTo = Sheets("Modify Order").Cells(7, 2).Value2
kCol = Sheets("Modify Order").Cells(5, 2).Value2
jLastRow = Sheets("Customer List").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
'
' get columns into variant arrays
'
vArrColE = Sheets("Customer List").Range("E1:E" & jLastRow).Value2
vArrColChange = Sheets("Customer List").Cells(1, kCol).Resize(jLastRow, 1).Value2

For j = LBound(vArrColE) To UBound(vArrColE)
    If vArrColE(j, 1) = myLookup Then
        vArrColChange(j, 1) = myChangeTo
        nChanged = nChanged + 1
    End If
Next j
'
' put changed column back
'
Sheets("Customer List").Cells(1, kCol).Resize(jLastRow, 1).Value2 = vArrColChange

Application.Calculation = lCalc
MsgBox "Changed " & nChanged & " Cells"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `AutoFilter()`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim myLookup As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    With Sheets("Modify Order")
        i = .Cells(5, 2).Value
        myLookup = .Cells(4, 2).Value
    End With
    With Sheets("Customer List")
        With .Range("E1", .Cells(.Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=myLookup
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .Offset(1, i).Resize(.Rows.count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = Sheets("Modify Order").Cells(7, 2).Value
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```